# Do you need access to the target OS's to code sign electron apps

Tags: electron, updates, code-signing, electron-builder, code-signing-certificate

I use Linux and am making an Electron App that I want to distribute on Windows, Mac, and Linux. All I want is that my app can update itself - but this requires code signing.

Does this mean I need to buy certificates for both windows and mac and buy computers to do the signing on?

Or can I just buy the certifcates and some how use them to sign on my Linux laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, only windows and mac need/support code signing at the application level.

You do need to get code certificates for both windows and mac that will verify your identity. You'd have to consult with the certificate vendor which platforms they support.

- On a mac you can sign both the windows binary and the mac app.
- On linux you can sign the windows binary, but not the mac app afaik.
- On windows, you can sign the windows binary, but not the mac app afaik.

From a build machine perspective it is therefore most efficient to build/sign on a mac, which supports signing the windows executable through JSign and the mac app.